# Android HERE SDK reverse geo code API issue under company's network

Tags: android, proxy, ssl-certificate, here-api, reverse-geocoding

I am using this ReverseGeocodeRequest2 to request information for the Geo coordinates. I got this on my logs before the request made.

```
private ResultListener<List<com.here.android.mpa.search.Location>> mGeocodeResultListener =
                new ResultListener<List<com.here.android.mpa.search.Location>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<com.here.android.mpa.search.Location> locations,
                                    ErrorCode errorCode) {

                Log.d(TAG, "geo code listener " + errorCode);

                if(errorCode == ErrorCode.NONE && locations != null && locations.size() >=1) {
                    for (com.here.android.mpa.search.Location location :
                            locations) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Geocode " + location.getAddress().toString());
                    }

                    Image marker = new Image();
                    marker.setBitmap(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                                    mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(
                                            "marker_car1_map_gps",
                                            "drawable",
                                            mContext.getPackageName()
                                    )
                            ));
                    mMap.addMapObject(new MapMarker(locations.get(0).getCoordinate(), marker));
                    mMap.setCenter(locations.get(0).getCoordinate(), Map.Animation.NONE);


                } else {
                    //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error " + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };

GeocodeRequest mGeocodeRequest = new     GeocodeRequest(address).setSearchArea(this.mMap.getCenter(),50);
            ErrorCode err_code = this.mGeocodeRequest.execute(mGeocodeResultListener);
            if (err_code == ErrorCode.NONE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Rev Geo Request is completed " );
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Rev Geo Request is completed " + err_code);
            }
```

`//error
03-07 10:31:10.453 27266-27266/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-07 10:31:11.006 27266-27283/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkProtocol: NetworkProtocol::NetworkProtocol
03-07 10:31:11.008 27266-27283/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkProtocol: NetworkProtocol::NetworkProtocol
03-07 10:31:11.022 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: NetworkSSLContextFactory created successfully
03-07 10:31:11.022 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: generateSSlContext BEGIN
03-07 10:31:11.093 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: The number of files 164 found in /storage/emulated/0/.here-maps/certs/
03-07 10:31:11.382 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: The number of valid certificates 164
03-07 10:31:11.427 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkSSLContextFactory: generateSSlContext END javax.net.ssl.SSLContext@13d84ca1
03-07 10:31:11.428 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
03-07 10:31:11.428 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc: getaddrinfo called from pid =27266
03-07 10:31:11.428 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
03-07 10:31:11.429 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
03-07 10:31:11.429 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc: getaddrinfo called from pid =27266
03-07 10:31:11.429 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
03-07 10:31:11.482 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/libc: dnsproxy getaddrinfo returns 0
03-07 10:31:11.482 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 I/System.out: propertyValue:false
03-07 10:31:12.369 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 E/NetworkProtocol: NetworkProtocol::GetTask::run exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
03-07 10:31:12.369 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:302)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:238)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:170)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:309)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:242)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:397)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:515)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
03-07 10:31:12.370 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.here.hype.NetworkProtocol$GetTask.run(NetworkProtocol.java:221)
03-07 10:31:12.371 27266-27328/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-07 10:31:12.592 27266-27283/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 D/NetworkProtocol: NetworkProtocol::NetworkProtocol`

Can I add my company's proxy certificates on HERE SDK certs?
Is there any way I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no, that is not possible for security reasons. We do not allow overriding of the certificate set used for authentication.